# Other words to replace "let's"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests, synonyms, idiom-requests

I am writing a project paper, and I find myself using the phrase "let's" a lot. I'm wondering if there are other phrases or words that I can use instead of "let's"? I've searched for an answer but couldn't find one.

Examples:

- We want to see x and y. **Let's** start with x.
- Now, **let us** see the relationship between z and w.

Comment: Can you give some examples?

Comment: Well, for one thing, you could avoid the contracted form and write it out in full i.e. "let us"

Comment: I added examples

Comment: **Let's start** =  We started with...  X was first in line....  **Let us see** = We will now see  the relationship.... The relationship between z and w was observed

Comment: Do note that this is not a writers' workshop. If you are overusing *let us*, just stop using it. You don't need to invite the reader to do every little thing. *To start, X is …. The relationship between z and w, on the other hand….* Otherwise, know that a basic search will turn up *let us* in innumerable journal articles, official proclamations, formal invitations, political speeches, and all manner of other speech and writing that would be deemed "formal" so it's unclear what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Mari-LouA and Choster for the information. I've removed "more-formal" from the question. I was actually searching for replacements, formal or not.

Comment: Romaine start with X. ...  Uh, oh!  I don't feel so good!

Answer (score 3):

Mari-Lou has shown that you could simply reduce the usage by modifying the base syntax

so for your examples

Examples:

> •We want to see x and y. **Starting** with x. ...
>     •Now, **observing** the relationship between z and w.

Thus you don't need to always change each Let's/Let *us* with a "replacement" however **we will** presume you do, **so we** could replace let us with

> •We want to see x and y. **We shall** start with x.
>     •Now, **we can** see the relationship between z and w.

Using *we* on occasion instead of *us* will avoid the sense of repetition

Answer (score 2):

"We want to see x and y." …

1. Let's start with x.
2. Starting with x, …
3. We'll start with x.
4. Looking at x first, …
5. In terms of seeing x, …
6. To see x, …
7. If we take x first, …

"Now, …"

1. let us see the relationship between z and w …
2. regarding the relationship between z and w …
3. starting with the relationship between z and w …
4. as for the relationship between z and w …

Just a few options. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have overused the term "Let's", how about using something like "Shall we explain" or maybe just not using something to describe who or what you're talking to, for example, "Firstly. . ." or "Starting with. . ."? I'm not too sure though, just an idea I came up with. :)

Answer (score -1):

'Let's do smth...' is a  suggestion.
According to  Cambridge Dictionary:
If we make a suggestion, it means that we mention a possible course of action to someone. There are a number of expressions which we can use to make suggestions.
For example:
How about / What about doing smth?
Or: 
Shall we do smth?
Or:
Let's do smth...